# Lenovo Ideapad Y700 - Ubuntu 15.10: Constant speaker noise after login

Tags: sound, lenovo, alsa, noise

I bought a new Lenovo Ideapad Y700 and tried Ubuntu 15.10 live on it. The speakers are making a constant noise after I login. I've recorded and shared the sound in soundcloud: https://soundcloud.com/user-964869845/speaker-noise

Does anyone know what is happening and how to solve this problem? Below is the output of lsusb && lspci commands:

```
$ lsusb && lspci
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 174f:14ea Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 191b (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #11 (rev f1)
00:1d.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #12 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X] (rev ff)
07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 3166 (rev 99)
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 524a (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

Let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks,
Bruno.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your audio driver using the [Instructions to upgrade ALSA](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS)